# Read git repository from composer

Tags: git, composer-php

I want install a project, stored in Gitlab, from Composer. So, i added the repository in composer.json:

```
"repositories": {
   "ramiro-md90": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://gitlab.com/ramiro-md90/mongozard.git"
   }
}
```

When i do `composer search ramiro-md90`, the project is listed:

```
rama@whitehawk:/var/www/rama.dev/rama-bundle$ composer search ramiro-md90
ramiro-md90/mongozard Mago para MongoDB
ramiro/sampledbaccess PDO Driver for Sybase Ase
```

But, when i try to read the package with `composer info ramiro-md90/mongozard`, composer says:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Package ramiro-md90/mongozard not found

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

By default `composer info ramiro-md90/mongozard` will show only installed packages, try:

```
composer info --all ramiro-md90/mongozard
```